# Xamarin android doesn't always deploy latest code changes

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm new to Xamarin/Android, and so far it's been a pretty frustrating experience, compounded by code/AXML changes seemingly not being built or deployed to the emulator. I often find that a change I've just made seems to get ignored when I build and run the app.

My suspicions were confirmed when it started throwing an exception on a line in MainActivity.cs that I had commented out. Cleaning and rebuilding didn't help, and in the end deleted the bin and obj folders and uninstalled the app off the emulator for good measure (not sure which of these fixed it though).

Is it just me or is this a common issue? Is there anything I can do to prevent it from happening? I'm using VS2015 Community by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'Tools/Configuration Manager' and make sure that both 'Build' and 'Deploy' options are checked for 'YourApp.Android' for active solution configuration and active solution platform. Then do 'Clean solution' and 'Rebuild solution', it should always work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a [common issue](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/45327/newest-version-of-code-not-always-deployed-when-debugging-from-xamarin-studio), as yet unresolved.

One of the comments in the above thread suggested that the problem can occur if you've only changed C# code, and unless you also "touch" one of the xml or axml files then the latest version won't be deployed. This seemed to do the trick in my case but it could have been a coincidence - Xamarin seems to be a temperamental beast, and will randomly fail to build or deploy on occasion, perhaps depending on the wind direction, or colour of my underwear that day.

I'm still in the early stages of learning Xamarin/Android, but if I don't enjoy the experience then I'll be jumping ship to Android Studio (although I'd prefer to stick with C# if I can).